# In how many ways we can spread around the table Wizard , King , Warrior , Elf , Dwarf and 4 Hobbits, with restrictions.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> In how many ways we can spread around the table wizard , King ,
>   Warrior , Elf , Dwarf and 4 Hobbits? Hobbit can not not sit side by
>   side with other hobbit and dwarf does not want to sit next to the elf. Table is circular and rotation of circle are considered the same.

I know that u can spread hobbits in 4! ways, but other thing i dont understand. Thank you for reply.

Comment: The real question is, where are the Men?? And do they like to sit next to Elves or Dwarves?? Are we to understand that the "Warriors" are men? And how does everyone feel about the wizards?

Comment: U shall not pass, Men are always warriors and they like elves and dwarves ;) And everyone likes everyone besides that dwarves dont like elfs.

Comment: Are the hobbits considered identical or distinct?  Is the table circular and rotations of the circle are considered the same?  Regardless the answers to these two questions, begin by placing the dwarf at the table.  Seat the wizard, king, warrior, and elf next.  Break into cases on whether the elf is adjacent to the dwarf or not.  Continue by placing the hobbits into the spaces between the other people, making sure to use the space between the elf and dwarf if currently adjacent.

Comment: I presume that they are identical, because 4! is correct answer to spread them. Table is circular and rotation of circle are considered the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- With the king seated as reference, seat the $4$ other than Hobbits in $4!$ ways.
- The Hobbits can be seated in the $5$ gaps in $^5P_4 = 5!$ ways,
  but this includes those where Elf and Dwarf may be together.
- To correct for this, glue the troublesome two as $DE$ or $ED$, and subtract these ways by repeating the procedure. The king + "other than Hobbits" can now be seated in $2\cdot3!$ ways, and the Hobbits inserted into the $4$ gaps in $4!$ ways.
- Putting things together, we get $4!\cdot5! - 2\cdot3!\cdot4! = 4!(5! - 2\cdot3!)$, the book answer.

Comment: why is there 5! ways if are only 4 gaps for them? i cant figure out where did u find 5 gaps. thank you

Comment: $K-H-H-H-H-K\;\;$ Imagine the diagram rolled up into circle so that the two $K's$ merge. As you can see, there are $5$ gaps $(-'s)$.